# Outlook VSTO Event when the explorer changed

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I need to work with the selection changed event on the active explorer object. But when I subscribe to the event `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange` on ribbon load, it only works for the currently active explorer.

Is there an event like active explorer changed or so?

I also tried to go through the list of explorers `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Explorers`, but that list only contains the explorers that were open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not set an event handler on an object returned from a multiple dot expression (e.g. `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer`) - you'd be setting an event handler on a temporary variable that will be released as soon as Garbage Collector gets to it. The object must be stored in a variable guaranteed to stay alive for your addin lifetime.

Secondly, Use the `Application.Explorers.NewExplorer` event to track new explorers (you can also use `Explorer.Close` event to release a particular Explorer object).

Create a wrapper class that stores `Explorer` object as its member (you can pass `Explorer` to its constructor) and sets up event handlers for the `Explorer.SelectionChange` and `Explorer.Close` events. In your addin, declare a list of wrappers (`List<MyExplorerWrapper>`). On startup, loop over all explorers in the `Application.Explorers` collection and set up an event handler for the `Explorers.NewExplorer` event (again, `Explorers` must be declared on the addin class level to keep it alive).

Comment: With releasing you mean to unsubscribe to the events?

Comment: Do you mean in Explorer.Close? Yes, unsubscribe form the events, release the object using Marshal.ReleaseComObject, and remove the wrapper class from the parent List<Explorer>.

Answer (score 1):

The [Explorers.NewExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorers.newexplorer) event is fired whenever a new explorer window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code.

The [Explorer.Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activate(even)) event is fired when an explorer becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code.