# Outlook VSTO-AddIn: Prevent Outlook from deleting an appointment

Tags: outlook-addin

I try to prohibit in certain cases that the user deletes an appointment. Something like this:

1. User clicks on appointment in calendar
2. User selects delete
3. VSTO-Addin checks whether this is allowed and shows a warning dialog in case if not. Outlook does NOT delete the appointment!

Currently I attached to Item_Delete_Add() and I think that one can only handle the deletion but you cannot prevent outlook from actually deleting the appointment. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue... The [Items.ItemRemove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemremove?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm316)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) event is fired when an item is deleted from the specified collection. This event does not run when the last item in a Personal Folders file (.pst) is deleted, or if 16 or more items are deleted at once from a PST file, Microsoft Exchange mailbox, or an Exchange public folder. Moreover, you must keep the reference to the source object to know which item is being deleted from a folder. To get this working you must subscribe to the `SelectionChange` event of the Explorer class. It is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. So, you could subscribe to every selected item and know which item exactly is removed.

Another possible way is to handle the [AppointmentItem.BeforeDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.AppointmentItem.BeforeDelete) event which is fired before an item (which is an instance of the parent object) is deleted. An instance of the item being deleted is passed as a parameter. In order for this event to fire when an email message, distribution list, journal entry, task, contact, or post are deleted through an action, an inspector must be open. The event occurs each time an item is deleted. It also allows to cancel the actions by setting the second parameter - if the event procedure sets this argument to `true`, the operation is not completed and the item is not deleted.

Yet another approach is to repurpose ribbon controls, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb462633(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more information.

Comment: I think your idea with catching SelectioChange events sounds as the best solution in general. From what I understand I need to attach to ActiveExplorer. Now my question is how would I get informed if the ActiveExplorer changes or is that something which is magically handled by Outlook. So do I need to reattach to the event handlers when the ActiveExplorer Window changes?

Comment: One more question: When I attach an event handler to the AppointmentItem.BeforeDelete and the user changes the current selection, do I need to unregister this as I otherwise would keep a pointer to the AppointmentItem which is prohibited:  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437362/outlook-addin-how-to-actively-release-memory-as-suggested-by-microsoft-document

Comment: Found it from you :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296917/outlook-vsto-event-when-the-explorer-changed